# Linear programming: Can objective variable have a constraint?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am having an issue with a LP problem. I'll first try to explain the problem in a simplified way, before explaining the issues.

**Basic problem**

Suppose I have three types of machines, all of which can only be operational for two periods of times (T1, T2, T3, or T4), as is indicated by the ones in the below matrix.

```
Machine T1    T2    T3   T4    Amount 
M1      0     1     1    0     x1     
M2      1     1     0    0     x2     
M3      0     0     1    1     x3
```

Each machine can produce any amount of items (x1 to x3; the variables). This is needed to achieve a MIMINUM required production per time period:

```
            T1  T2  T3  T4
Required    2   3   1   1
```

To solve this problem, we need:

- `M2` to produce 2,
- `M3` to produce 1,
- either `M1` or `M2` to produce 1, with the effect that one too many is produced at T3 or T1 respectively.

which may result in:

```
Machine T1    T2    T3   T4    Amount 
M1      0     0     0    0     0     
M2      3     3     0    0     3     
M3      0     0     1    1     1      

prod    3     3     1    1
Requ    2     3     1    1
```

**Constraints**

Production during T1 and T4 is not preferrable and should be punished. In the above example, this would mean that `M1` should be used to produce.

In simple wording, the problem states to **produce at least the required amount, but minimize any excess (especially in T1 and T4).**

This can be done in two ways:

- The machines operational during these periods are punished (Punishment by M; M2 and M3).
- The production per time period is punished (Punished by T; T1 and T4)

This would look as follows:

```
Machine T1    T2    T3   T4    Amount   Pm
M1      0     1     1    0     x1       0
M2      1     1     0    0     x2       0.5
M3      0     0     1    1     x3       0.5

Pt      0.5   0     0    0.5
```

**Issue**: 
I can only get the punishment per machine to work properly. Punishment by time is not infeasible, but gives incorrect output (way too many redundant machines).

**Attempt and outcome**

I first programmed the solver with a punishment by m (Pm). 
The objective function (in Python pulp) here is:

```
amount = LpVariable.dicts("amount_",Machine,0,100000,LpInteger)
product_t = LpVariable.dicts("product_",time,0,100000,LpInteger)


prob += lpSum([amount[m]*(1+Pm[m]) for m in Machine]) # minimize

# constraint
for t in time:
    # production per time period; matrix[m,t] is the matrix with ones shown above
    product_t[t] = lpSum([amount[m] * matrix[m,t] for m in machine])
    # production must be higher than required. 
    prob += product_t[t] >= req[t]
```

The outcome in this situation would be (Machine, production, punishment): 
`M1 * 1 * (0+1) + M2 * 2 * (0.5+1) + M3 * 1 * (0.5+1) = 5.5` compared to the suboptimal solution: `M1 * 0 * (0+1) + M2 * 3 * (0.5+1) + M3 * 1 * (0.5+1) = 6`

Following, because this approach has some downsides in the real situation, I wanted to calculate it with punishment by t (Pt).

```
prob += lpSum([product_t[t]*(1+Pt[t]) for t in time]) #minimize

for t in time:  # same calculation of product_t and constraint as above
    product_t[t] = lpSum([amount[m] * matrix[m,t] for m in machine])
    prob += inzet_t[t] >= nodig[t]
```

This approach, however, gives me a feasible but incorrect output (production = 0.0).

### Question

**How is it possible that, with exactly the same constraints, the punishment by time does not work?** Is it not allowed that the objective function contains a variable (`product_t`) with a constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was starting to disect the code more and more and found out the following:
`amount` and `product_t` were defined in the same way. However, saying `amount[m].varValue` is possible, but saying `product_t[t].varValue` was not (LpAffineExpression has no attribute called varValue). Instead, I had to say `value(product_t[t])`. I think this is because `amount` is used to calculate `product_t`, and `product_t` is thus a different kind of variable. So I knew I had to look at the use of `product_t` in the objective formula

**Attempt 1:**  failed but it was a longshot

```
prob +=  lpSum([value(product_t[t])*Pt[t] for t in time  ]) #added value() 
# Error: Unsupported operant * for NoneType and float`
```

**Attempt 2:** was a success.

In the goal function `prob += lpSum([product_t[t]*(1+Pt[t]) for t in time]) #minimize` I replaced `product_t` with the formula to calculate it. So, the objective function was:

```
prob += lpSum([product_t[t]*(1+Pt[t]) for t in time]) #OLD
```

and became

`prob +=  lpSum([lpSum([amount[i] * timeblock_matrix[i,t] for i in dienst])*Pt[t] for t in time]) #NEW, minimize`

---

If one could explain why it works like, why it cannot have an intermediate LpVariable, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, your problem is

**sets:**

- `M = {m1, m2, m3}` machines
- `T = {t1, t2, t3, t4}` time periods

**decision variables:**

- `p[m,t]` binary: does machine `m` operate in time period `t`?

**constraints:**

- minimum production: in your question named required

  - `sum_m(t1)=2`
  - `sum_m(t2)=3`
  - `sum_m(t3)=1`
  - `sum_m(t4)=1`
- maximum operational times

  - `sum_t(m1)=2`
  - `sum_t(m2)=2`
  - `sum_t(m3)=2`

**objective**

- `min C sum_m(t1)+sum_m(t2)+sum_m(t3)+C sum_m(t4)`, where `C>1` is penalty for operating in the first or last time period.

I think if you agree that this would solve your problem then it should be possible to transfer this model to code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, the binary operation time is not the decision variabe but a fixed variable. X, the amount of machines, is the decision variable. There is thus some sumproduct/nested-loops works for calculating production (see also the resulting objective function in my answer) . The reason I use all these for loops is because the problem in reality is a lot bigger (thousands of rows, almost a hundrerd time periods).

Comment: What do you mean by "binary operation time"? And what is a "fixed variable"? It is possible to reflect the wish to use as few as possible machines in the objective, however not without setting an upper bound for available machines.

Comment: With binary operation time I meant the matrix, what you thought was the decision variable. There are machines (options) that can only operate on time blocks with the ones. That is fixed, thus it cannot be changed. The decision variable, X, is the amount of times you apply each machine. Applying machine 1 two times, results in production, indexed by time, of `0 2 2 0`. The goal is to have a combination of all machines where the joint production, again indexed by time, is equal or higher than what is required. The sumproduct of production and punishment is the objective that must be minimized.

Comment: So the constraints "maximum operational time" in my proposal should be replaced by `p[m,t]==0` for  the time slots `t` where it is not allowed to operate the machine `m`. How do I know that the production of machine 1 is 2 (if operating). Is there an output rate for all machines, or an upper bound for max. production of a machine?

Comment: Thank you for all the effort of trying to understand the issue, but I think I cannot explain it any better. Not via comments anyway. But the issue is resolved right now (see my own answer), so I think it is best to save further energy. Thank you anyways :)